# SPIGOT: Calling a non-static method without re-initializing the plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I've spent upwards of the last 4 days researching and trying to figure this issue out. Sadly because of the poor documentation and lack of community support related to my issue I've finally decided to turn to StackOverflow.

Here's my issue, every Java programmer knows or should know, that you should essentially NEVER use *static* variables, classes, methods etc correct?
Well, it seems as tho any time I try to call a method from an external class (By starting a new instance of my main class where the non-static method is stored), Spigot throws a *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!* error!

So here's my question, how do I get an instance of my main class and run a method from said class (from an external class), without triggering this error? As I've said, I've scoured the internet trying to find an answer to this issue. The most logically sound answer I've gotten can be found here posted by **Father of Time**: https://bukkit.org/threads/how-do-you-refer-to-a-non-static-method.69920/

I've changed **Father of Time**'s given answer to match my needs (The method I'm trying to access is located in my main class as opposed to some other class)
Here's my current, applicable code:

**Main Class**

```
public final class MainClass extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    private static final MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();

...

    public MainClass() {}

    public static MainClass getMainClass()
    {
        return mainClass;
    }

    private void exampleMethod() {
    }

...

}
```

**Secondary Class**

```
import com.example.namespace.MainClass;

...

public class CommandClass implements CommandExecutor {

...
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {

         MainClass.getMainClass().exampleMethod()

    }

...

}
```

The reasoning behind **Father of Time**'s description is that we don't make the class itself or any of its variables/methods static. But rather, simply grab an instance of the class using a static getter.
Everything about this looks like it should work (it compiles just fine too).

I am pretty new to Java and honestly, lots of the stuff related to cross-class communication has been hard for me to wrap my head around. To be clear, this is simply me making experimental plugins to help myself learn the language (I learn faster by doing as opposed to just reading haha). I already know that going static crazy is a bad practice which is why I'm so frustrated that, even tho I'm trying to do the right thing, I can't find a single answer on the internet that works!

Any help/constructive criticism is greatly appreciated! I hope to eventually get to a point where I can start writing awesome plugins for Minecraft, but I need to get used to the Java environment first.

Comment: How are you using `CommandShowControl`? You should pass a `MainClass` instance when you create an instance of `CommandShowControl`.

Comment: @Sweeper Just wanted to say that I've renamed `CommandShowControl` to `CommandClass` (so It'll make more sense in the scope of this question.)
Anyways, you're saying to include something inside `CommandClass` like `private MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();` right?

Comment: I'm asking you to show how and where you are creating an instance of `CommandClass`.

Comment: The reason for the error is because your main class extends `JavaPlugin`, so you can't make a new instance of it. Instead you should have another class with all the relevant methods that you can make a new instance from. Without seeing more of your code and knowing exactly what you are trying to do it will be very hard to help. Note that static variables can safely be used in spigot plugins, but you need to know when and where to use them. Static variables are great for values that don't change, but they are no good if for variables that are used for different uses/players .

Comment: @sorifiend thank you for this! I'll kep it in mind!

Comment: @Sweeper one moment actually. What you said prompted me to do a google search for something. aaannndddd I might've maybe found my answer (I'm actually gonna be a little mad if this works tbh) If it does I'll post hte answer

Comment: I am not sure, but if `MainClass` as a `JavaPlugin` will only be initialized once, try to assign to the static variable (probably should be named `INSTANCE` instead of `mainClass`) in your constructor. When other classes need access to the `MainClass` instance they can just call the getter.

Comment: @Deadbeef thank you for your comment! I actually found my answer completely by accident just a moment ago! But what I did (it was option 2 in the link I shared in my answer) is basically exactly what you just said, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I can't even begin to say how slightly annoyed but also relieved I am to have figured this out after spending half an hour writing out my question XD
Prompted by something @Sweeper said in a comment. I ran another google search. and I found this link:

> https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/best-method-for-getting-instance-of-main-class.365480/

I was immediately able to replace my code and get everything working! As I said, I'm still very noob in this field, to me when I add the `new MainClass()` line in my MainClass I saw THAT as my calling the class' instance. So I never even thought that I wasn't doing it.

When Sweeper said "I'm asking you to show how and where you are creating an instance of CommandClass" I was like, "Wait I thought X was me getting the instance" thus causing me to search it a bit more and come to the conclusion that I'm.... an idiot.

As simple of an issue, it was, I can't believe it stumped me for so long! Thank you Sweeper for you indirectly answering my question! :D